# Find all combinations with i 0s and (n-i) 1s in array of size n.

Tags: python, combinations, combinatorics

I've been trying to solve this with itertools.product() and itertools.permutations(), but still can't find the combinatorics I need. Apologies if this has been asked before, but I have searched everywhere to no avail.

For example, given a byte array of size 6, how can I easily iterate through all possible sets with 2 zeros and 4 ones? i.e., the following sequence (hope I have it right):

- 001111
- 010111
- 011011
- 011101
- 011110
- 100111
- 101011
- 101101
- 101110
- 110011
- 110101
- 110110
- 111001
- 111010
- 111100

I understand the size of the sequence will be n!/((n-i)!*i!) but I can't wrap my brain over iterating through individual combinations. I I will be working with arrays up to size 10,000, so looping over all possible "01" permutations and discarding what doesn't fit would be too inefficient for me. The order of the output also does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> seq_len = 6
>>> _0_count = 2
>>> positions = range(seq_len)
>>> _0_positions = combinations(positions, _0_count)
>>> [[0 if i in zpos else 1 for i in positions] for zpos in _0_positions]
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

**note:** This can be reduced to a one liner but you would lose meaningful names.  To save memory change the outer list comprehension into a generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
positions = range(1, 7)
itertools.combinations(positions, 4)
```

That will give you all the combinations of `1` positions you need.